# Compare line from file to input from form in javascript

Tags: javascript

My aim is to compare the first line of a text file to input recieved from a form.
My code successfully reads from the file,after that I use the following code

```
  var lines=result.split("\n");   //this line turns file into array
  var line=lines[i].split(" ");   //each index is further changed into an   array         
  var sentence=lines[i].split(" ").join(" ").toLowerCase();   //this turns the line/sentence from an array into a String
  var input=document.getElementById('inputFromForm').value.toLowerCase(); //this line get input from form

 console.log(sentence);    //this prints the first line of the text file to the console
 console.log(input);     //this prints the inputFromForm to the text file
 console.log(sentence==input);  //check for equality
```

My problem is that both sentences are equal but the console says false to

```
 console.log(sentence==input);
```

How is that possible,and why.

Comment: try console.log(sentence.trim()==input.trim());

Comment: what exactly is sentence and input? what do the console.log's produce?

Comment: you should also use `===` not `==`, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: Thanks mate.I tried it now and it woks.

Comment: @AbdurahmanHaydar you should accept the answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the below methods

```
console.log(sentence.trim()==input.trim());

console.log(sentence.toLowerCase()==input.toLowerCase());

console.log(sentence.localeCompare(input)==0);
```

Comment: [use ===](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: both are string what is the use of ===

Comment: [*My advice is to never use **the evil twins**. Instead, always use === and !==. All of the comparisons just shown produce false with the === operator*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons). `==` is very inconsistent in it's behaviour and should typically **never** be used. e.g. `"abc" == new String("abc") //false`, both are strings...

Answer (score 2):

You can use different approaches.

**Approach I:**

```
    var str1 = "ab abcde";
    var str2 = "ab abcde";
    var n = str1.localeCompare(str2);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
```

- Returns -1 if str1 is sorted before str2
- Returns 0 if the two strings are equal
- Returns 1 if str1 is sorted after str2

For more details check: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_localecompare.asp

**Approach II:**

You can match each word in the sentence using a for loop.

```
var s1 = 'Example 1';
var s2 = 'Example 2';

var s1Array= s1.split(' ');
var s2Array= s2.split(' ');

var result = 0;

for(var i = 0; i<s1Array.length; i++)
{
     if(s1Array[i] !== s2Array[i]){
         result=-1;   
         return;
     }
}

if(result<0){//strings not equal}
```

This approach can also be used to find how much similar the two sentences are. I have mentioned this approach here as you are splitting the sentence into array, so you can use this approach too.

Answer (score 1):

Check like this

**Syntax :**

```
str1.localeCompare(str2)
```

Explanation of localeCompare: It will

- Returns -1 if str1 is sorted before str2
- Returns 0 if the two strings are equal
- Returns 1 if str1 is sorted after str2

So

```
Console.log(sentence.localeCompare(input));
```

So your two strings are equal it will provide 0.